# Elisp: possible to automatically open Emacs init file if error at start-up?

Tags: emacs, error-handling, elisp

Here's the idea: if I restart Emacs after making a change to my Emacs init file, it would be very convenient if, in the event of an error at start-up, Emacs automatically opened my init file for editing

For example, if there's an error at start-up, Emacs could show the error/debug message in one window and my init file in the other window.

I'm new to Emacs Lisp and am not familiar with error-handling procedures.  Are there any error-handling mechanisms/settings that could be useful?  (Am honestly not sure where to even start with this one, hence the lack of any experimental code in this post...)

Comment: I would recommending starting by placing this at the beginning of your `.emacs` file:   `(setq debug-on-error t)`  After you fix your problem, you can comment it out again until needed.  The `error` halts Emacs, so what you seek would require redefining the error signal function to do something else before quitting whatever function is running.

Comment: lawlist - can you make your post into an answer so i can accept it?   thanks

Comment: actually, i just saw Drew's answer below.  his answer includes an implementation of the method you propose so probably good if future visitors are directed to that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do that, you can try this:

Wrap the contents of your init file in this, where `CONTENTS` is your originaly init file, and FILE is the absolute name (i.e., location) of your init file:

```
(condition-case err
     (progn
        (setq debug-on-error  t)
        CONTENTS
     )
  (error (find-file FILE)
         (error "*INIT ERROR*: %s" (error-message-string err))))
```

Or perhaps a little better: Put what is in your init file now in another file - called ORIG-INIT here (again, an absolute file name), and use this as the (only) content of your init file:

```
(condition-case err
     (progn (setq debug-on-error  t)
            (load-file ORIG-INIT))
  (error (find-file ORIG-INIT)
         (error "*INIT ERROR*: %s" (error-message-string err))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I normally have one emacs open with the .emacs file. Then I open and close a new emacs every time I've made changes. Not as cool, I know, but then even your cursor will be where you were working.

Another thing I do is just edit a piece of code in a scrap buffer (*scratch* or a newly made temporary file) and execute it using C-x C-e (while standing at the end of the expression).